# "No suitable download server found"

Tags: server, apt, updates, update-manager, proxy

I bumped into the problem that I can't download any updates or new packages.
I had this problem before  which I could solve through several steps

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

This gives me still a

```
W: Failed to fetch
http://ucmirror.canterbury.ac.nz/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages
404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
```

I tried a different server by hand, and get a 'No suitable download server found' when I ask Ubuntu to find one for me.
I am not behind a firewall, there is no proxy server set up in the settings or anything like that.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 12.10 "Quantal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you version of ubuntu is end of life, you can change your version or you can replace the soures in /etc/apt/sources.list,

1)you can do this manually by changing the sources to old-releases.ubuntu.com

2)in terminal by sudo sed -i -e 's/ucmirror.canterbury.ac.nz\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, the version of Ubuntu you are using is `Ubuntu 12.10 quantal`.

This version is out of its support time, you need to install a newer release.
For this, see [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

The actual error is that the server does not longer have package files for `quantal`.

For details on the support times of releases, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases
Quantal is listed in table "End of life".